# Can PHP use localhost timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone

I recently had a glitch in some PHP code running on my local Windows machine (using IIS).

I had moved timezones, and the problem occurred because MySQL uses the local machine time for functions like NOW(), but PHP determines its timezone from the php.ini file (or from functions like date_default_timezone_set).

I was creating records with a timestamp (coming from PHP), that should be deleted once they are more than 15 minutes old (using NOW() within MySQL).  Because of the difference in timezone, they were always more than 15 minutes old.

I move around a bit, and I may not always remember to update my php.ini file to my current timezone.

PHP gets its current timezone from the *date.timezone* setting in its ini file.  I thought maybe removing this altogether would work, but instead it defaults to UTC.

I realise that one option is to just be consistent in whether I use PHP's time or MySQL's time, but I'm curious to know if there is a way to just tell PHP to use whatever the timezone is of the machine it is running on.

Thanks

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php to set the timezone. As for how to get the name of the timezone of the local machine, I don't know. I know how you would go about it on Linux or Mac, but don't know how to do it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, one method would be to execute the shell command `tzutil /g` with `exec()` and read the output, which in my case reports `Central Standard Time`.

Since that doesn't seem to be an accepted format for `date_default_timezone_set()`, at least according to the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), but you could have a short array of Windows outputs and corresponding PHP-accepted timezones.

Comment: Great info. Didn't know about tzutil. I've decided the safest bet is to just standardise both parts to use PHP time. At least that way it's consistent (though I still have to be careful about Daylight Saving Time).